# rotated image is going out of parent div

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to rotate the image, but it is going out of parent div.

```
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg">
  <button class="rotate-button">rotate image</button>
</div>

jquery code

$('.rotate-button').on('click', function() {
  var image = $(this).prev('img');
  image.className = "rotated_90deg";
});
```

unrotated state:

[image]

rotated state: 
[image]

how can I keep the image smaller in rotated state, so that it does not go out of parent div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the solution with `scale` property

```js
$('.rotate-button').on('click', function() {
  var image = $(this).prev('img');
  image.className = "rotated_90deg";
});
```

```css
.rotated_90deg {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.5, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1907a.jpg">
  <button class="rotate-button">rotate image</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

"tranform rotate" does just that. It retains its original height, and the forging is done in a separate visual layer.

the best thing you can do is set the height of the area where the image rotates equal to the largest side of the image

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const {offsetHeight, offsetWidth} = img;
if(offsetWidth >= offsetHeight) {
  img.parentElement.style.height = offsetWidth + 'px';
}


const rotations = [];
const rotateImage = () => {
  rotations.push('rotate(45deg)');
  img.style.transform = rotations.join(' ');
}
```

```css
div { display: flex; }
img { transition: .3s; margin: auto; }
button { display: block;  margin: auto; position: relative }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
</div>
<button onclick=rotateImage()>Rotate</button>
```

hmm ... maybe I hastened to answer.
As a solution, "position: relative;" on the button

Answer (score 1):

Put the image inside a container div, give it an id or class and set the overflow to hidden:

```
.imgContainer{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or if you want the picture to scale so it fits within the div, set max width and height:

```
.imgContainer img{
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```